# Estimar variável de difícil isolamento

Tags: r

Boa tarde colaboradores.
Estou com dificuldade de estimar um parâmetro via programação em R para completar minha rotina de processamentos. 
A equação que estou utilizando é a descrita a seguir, onde tenho todos os valores, menos o valor da variável k

```
razao2 = (razao1)^((idade2/idade)^k)
```

onde, tenho os vetores

```
razao2<-c(1.0331279, 1.0416188, 1.0167619, 0.0000000, 0.9638364, 0.9668588)
razao1<-c(1.0151796, 1.0331279, 1.0416188, 1.0167619, 0.9822768, 0.9638364)
idade<-c(2.580833, 3.594167, 4.608333, 2.580833, 3.594167, 4.608333)
idade2<-c(3.594167, 4.608333, 5.625000, 3.594167, 4.608333, 5.625000)
```

`razao1[1]` é respectivo a `razao2[1]`, respectivo a `idade[1]` e a `idade2[1]`

portanto para cada posição `i` dos vetores , terei um valor calculado de `k` que promove a igualdade

Tentei fazer via seguinte caminho, porém não obtive sucesso, estou com dificuldades de conseguir criar uma lógica q isole k para ser estimado, ou que de algum outro meio promova as estimativas de um valor de k para casa combinações de valores de uma dada posição `i` dos vetores

```
kcalculado <- function(razao1, idade2, idade, k){
  razao2 <- razao1^((idade2/idade)^(k)) 
  razao2
}

optimise(kcalculado, razao2)
```

desde já agradeço a ajuda

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utilizando a fórmula anterior à fórmula final da [resposta do Marcelo Shiniti Uchimura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/363208/estimar-vari%c3%a1vel-de-dif%c3%adcil-isolamento/363214#363214), podemos ajustar um modelo linear.

```
#ln(ln(razao2) = ln(ln(razao1)) + ln(idade2/idade1)*k

log.log.razao1 <- log(log(razao1))
log.log.razao2 <- log(log(razao2))
log.id2.id <- log(idade2/idade)

modelo <- lm(log.log.razao2 ~ log.id2.id)

r1 <- exp(exp(coef(modelo)[1]))
k <- exp(coef(modelo)[2])
```

Neste resultado, `r1` é o valor calculado de `razao1`, que não está muito afastado do valor médio dos dados.

```
mean(razao1)
#[1] 1.0088

r1
#(Intercept) 
#   1.009239
```

E o valor de `k` será o seguinte.

```
k
#log.id2.id 
#  73.33412
```

Se estes nomes forem incomodativos, pode-se fazer `unname(r1)` e `unname(k)`.

Answer (score 3):

Abaixo, a álgebra.

```
razao2 = (razao1)^((idade2/idade1)^k)

ln(razao2) = (idade2/idade1)^k * ln(razao1)

ln(ln(razao2)) = k * ln(idade2/idade1) + ln(ln(razao1))

k = (ln(ln(razao2)) - ln(ln(razao1))) / (ln(idade2) - ln(idade1))
```